# timing issues in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I think i have a timing issue. It perplexes me why.

On the trigger of an event I call a function to update a value:

```
Private Sub t0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles t0.Click
    Input.ppProperty = "blank"
    UpdateRecord("Hey", Input.ppProperty)
    MsgBox(Input.ppProperty)
End Sub
```

UpdateRecord() should update the property Input.ppProperty to the value "Hey". It does update it, but not until UpdateRecord() has finished. The code:

```
Sub UpdateRecord(ByVal updateValue As String, ByRef recordToUpdate As String)
    If recordToUpdate <> Nothing Then
        MsgBox(updateValue & " " & recordToUpdate & " " & Input.ppProperty)
    End If
    recordToUpdate = updateValue
    If recordToUpdate <> Nothing Then
        MsgBox(updateValue & " " & recordToUpdate & " " & Input.ppProperty)
    End If
End Sub
```

Output:

> Hey Blank Blank    'initial values 
>      Hey Hey Blank    'values at the end of the function 
>      Hey    'value of property when function is finished

What it seems like it should be is:

Desired Output:

> Hey Blank Blank 'initial values 
>      Hey Hey Hey 'values at the end of the function 
>      Hey 'value of property when function is finished

Notice the difference, the property does not update until the function is completely finished. 
Why?

**EDIT:**
Also, how would I go about fixing this so it updates within the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a property `ByRef`, the equivalent of the following happens:

```
Dim temporaryValue As String = Input.ppProperty
UpdateRecord("Hey", temporaryValue)
Input.ppProperty = temporaryValue
```

There’s no direct way around this. A potential solution is to rewrite the `UpdateRecord` method so that you can pass the whole object (`Input`) into it and manipulate the property value directly. Only then will the change be reflected directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, big help!

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that it has something to do with `Strings` in .Net being an immutable type.

You get a temporary string that is passed in ByRef and then Returned out causing the `Input.ppProperty` to be set afterwards.

Something like this:

```
Dim tempInput As String = Input.ppProperty
UpdateRecord("Hey", tempInput)
Input.ppProperty = tempInput
```

Since it seems that `Input` is in Scope in both cases why not do this as so.

```
Sub UpdateRecord(ByVal updateValue As String)

    Input.ppProperty = updateValue

End Sub
```

However if this actually isn't the case I'll need to think about this a little more.

Comment: I could do that, but I have to use this function[edit: properties] to update thirty or so other functions. I don't want to use a giant case statement if I can avoid it.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean properties? But that's what I kind of presumed. Is there any reason you can't set the property directly?

Comment: Yea, properties. The function is actually a lot more complicated and deals with a lot of business rules and error checking. I reduced it down to the relevant part for SO.

Comment: No, that’s actually not the reason. VB does definitely *not* implement reference passing via [call-by-value-return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore) (that’s what you’re describing). VB uses real call-by-reference. Whether or not the type is immutable is therefore quite irrelevant. The only important factor here is that a *property* is passed into the method, instead of a variable.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I did not actually realize that, that is quite useful to know.

Comment: @Oak I'm not sure if having a generic function for updating a single item is the best choice then. Is there any reason you can't just do the validation on a property change (Using something like INotifyProperyChanged)

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. (Im rather new at all this). I have never used INotifyProperyChanged. I have thirty or so properties that need updated at various times, and it takes forty or so lines of code that is all identical except for the property that is to be updated. I ended up using the CallByName() method.

Comment: @Oak INotifyPropertyChanged is a Interface that your class implements that raises an event when a properties value is changed. During this event you could call the appropriate validation code. You're already calling the code each time it is called anyways and this is a lot cleaner I would think.